# Poor (and loud) quality out of good Bluetooth headphones on Monterey

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones, monterey

I'm getting horrible audio quality out of some good headphones, and it's too loud even at the lowest possible volume setting.  It sounds as if it's clipped, and then the clipped signal has been amplified, preserving the distortion.

I'm on a 16in M1 Max MBP running 12.3.1 (the latest as of this post).  The headphones with this problem are AirPods Pro, Beats Flex, and Shure AONIC 215.  All 3 sound just fine on my iPhone.  I also tried a pair of AirPods Max, and that does not have this problem -- it sounds fine and a comfortable volume is about mid-range.

I tried the trick to fine-adjust volume, which helps get it down to comfortable levels, but it is still distorting.

This seems to have begun occurring after a recent software update -- all 3 problematic headphones worked fine a month ago.  Any suggestions on how to reset the audio preferences or other fixes?

Comment: What app are you using and are you using the microphone?

Comment: That was the problem.  I've had OBS open in the background for a while since I use it somewhat often.  Turns out it's capturing the mic even when muted and not actively streaming (according to Control Center).  Quit it and the audio quality suddenly got a lot better.